# MouseMove in a panel containing a Label

Tags: vb.net, label, panel, mouseover

I would like to move a panel in reaction to the MouseMove Event, but this event isn't triggered if the mouse is over the label inside the panel. (It is triggered if the mouse is inside the panel but outside of the label). Is there a simple way to fix this ?

I'm using Visual Basic 2010.

Comment: not a .net expert but in java you would add the listener to the label to or over ride the low level event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do that :

```
Private Sub MyControl_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    'Something it does when clicked
End Sub

Private Sub MyControl_ControlAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlAdded
    AddHandler e.Control.Click, AddressOf MyControl_Click
    AddHandler e.Control.ControlAdded, AddressOf MyControl_ControlAdded
End Sub
```

I just have to do the same with MouseOver.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own class derive from the Panel and use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove.aspx

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnMouseMove ( e As MouseEventArgs )
```

this will give you access to all mouse move events over the panel

Comment: is the method being called are you using this panel? add a logger? in java you need to enable these can you read the doc of this class?

Comment: The override method is beeing only called when the mouse is over the panel but outside of the label which is inside the panel. So I guess don't need to enable the method, but the problem remains.

Comment: well a workaround would be to have a seperate listener class and add it to the label and the panel. very strange though. maybe you should post this on the vb.net forums at microsoft as seems not any .net people around here

Comment: the label is a child of the panel you have made?